QAOA not working for TSP with 3 cities on Qiskit
I am trying to learn QAOA algorithm, and trying to code by reading the link https://learning.quantum.ibm.com/tutorial/quantum-approximate-optimization-algorithm
The code i am writing  to simulate on my local machine is :
'import numpy as np
from qiskit_aer import Aer
from qiskit_aer.primitives import sampler
from qiskit_algorithms import QAOA, NumPyMinimumEigensolver
from qiskit_algorithms.optimizers import optimizer
from qiskit_optimization.algorithms import MinimumEigenOptimizer
from qiskit_optimization.applications import Tsp
 from qiskit_optimization.converters import QuadraticProgramToQubo
from qiskit.circuit.library.n_local.qaoa_ansatz import QAOAAnsatz
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Session



 n = 3
 num_qubits = n ** 2
 distance_matrix = np.array([
 [0, 48, 91],
 [48,  0, 63],
 [91, 63,  0],])
 tsp=Tsp(distance_matrix)
 qp = tsp.to_quadratic_program()
 print(qp.prettyprint())
 qp2qubo = QuadraticProgramToQubo()
 qubo = qp2qubo.convert(qp)
 print(qubo.prettyprint())

 cost_hamiltonian, offset = qubo.to_ising()
 print(offset)
 print(cost_hamiltonian)




 circuit = QAOAAnsatz(cost_operator=cost_hamiltonian, reps=2)
 circuit.measure_all()
 circuit.parameters
 from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
 backend = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator_statevector')
 print(backend)
 pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(optimization_level=3,backend=backend)
 candidate_circuit = pm.run(circuit)
 candidate_circuit.draw('mpl', fold=False, idle_wires=False)
 initial_gamma = np.pi
 initial_beta = np.pi/2
 init_params = [initial_gamma, initial_beta, initial_gamma, initial_beta]


 def cost_func_estimator(params, ansatz, hamiltonian, estimator):

# transform the observable defined on virtual qubits to
# an observable defined on all physical qubits
isa_hamiltonian = hamiltonian.apply_layout(ansatz.layout)

pub = (ansatz, isa_hamiltonian, params)
job = estimator.run([pub])

results = job.result()[0]
cost = results.data.evs
print(cost)

objective_func_vals.append(cost)


 return cost
 from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Session, EstimatorV2 as Estimator
 from scipy.optimize import minimize
  from qiskit_ibm_runtime import SamplerV2 as Sampler

  objective_func_vals = [] # Global variable
  with Session(backend=backend) as session:
# If using qiskit-ibm-runtime<0.24.0, change `mode=` to `session=`
estimator = Estimator(mode=session)
estimator.options.default_shots = 1000

# Set simple error suppression/mitigation options


result = minimize(
    cost_func_estimator,
    init_params,
    args=(candidate_circuit, cost_hamiltonian, estimator),
    method="COBYLA",
    tol=1e-6,
)
print(result)
optimized_circuit = candidate_circuit.assign_parameters(result.x)
sampler = Sampler(mode=session)
sampler.options.default_shots = 10000

Set simple error suppression/mitigation options
pub= (optimized_circuit, )
job = sampler.run([pub], shots=int(1e4))
counts_int = job.result()[0].data.meas.get_int_counts()
counts_bin = job.result()[0].data.meas.get_counts()
shots = sum(counts_int.values())
final_distribution_int = {key: val/shots for key, val in counts_int.items()}
final_distribution_bin = {key: val/shots for key, val in counts_bin.items()}
print(final_distribution_int)

Find the bitstring with the highest probability
    most_likely_bitstring_int = max(final_distribution_int, key=final_distribution_int.get)
    most_likely_bitstring_bin = max(final_distribution_bin, key=final_distribution_bin.get)
    print(f"Most likely bitstring (int): {most_likely_bitstring_int}")
    print(f"Most likely bitstring (binary): {most_likely_bitstring_bin}")'

  The result that I am getting is 
  message: Optimization terminated successfully.
  success: True
  status: 1
  fun: -1304.0579420579418
   x: [ 2.521e+00  1.384e+00  2.585e+00  1.050e+00]
   nfev: 58
   maxcv: 0.0

    Most likely bitstring (int): 393
    Most likely bitstring (binary): 110001001

where is the issue? can somebody explain? I get the feeling it has something to do with the session, estimator and sampler commands
